# Vanilla JavaScript - Appending Elements and Txt to an Element without using .innerHTML

Tags: javascript, domdocument, microsoft-edge

element.append() not working in MS Edge

I was wondering how is the best way to create a new element and then append a string into it made up of other elements ang text variables? The .append method doesn’t seem to work in MS Edge
The error I’m getting is: SCRIPT438: SCRIPT438: Object doesn't support property or method 'append'

Isn’t this the correct way to do this without creating a string and then append to the parent.inner HTML??

parent = document.createElement("h4");

txtNode = document.createTextNode("");
txtNode.append(“WHATEVER”);

parent.appendChild(txtNode):

Thanks in advance

```html
// Const
const numCopyrightTxtYear = 2018;       

// Copyright Var
var elmCopyright = document.createElement("h4");
var elmCopyrightTxt = document.createTextNode("");

// Elements to append to elmCopyrightTxt
var elmTime = document.createElement("time");
var elmTimeTxt = document.createTextNode(numCopyrightTxtYear);
var elmCopyrightHolder = document.createElement("em");
var elmCopyrightHolderTxt = document.createTextNode("")

// Copyright
elmTime.dateTime = numCopyrightTxtYear;
elmTime.setAttribute("itemprop", "copyrightYear");
elmCopyrightHolder.setAttribute("itemprop", "creator copyrightHolder");
elmCopyrightHolder.appendChild(elmCopyrightHolderTxt);
elmCopyright.append("© ");
elmTime.appendChild(elmTimeTxt);
elmCopyright.append(elmTime);
elmCopyright.append(elmCopyrightHolder);



// This is the compleat code if I left somthing out??

function createHeaderFragment() {

            // Main Fragment
            var elmHeaderFragment = document.createDocumentFragment();
            // Other Containers
            var elmHeader = document.createElement("header");

            // Values to Set
            const strTitle = "Title";
            const strCaption = "Caption";
            const strSubjectOf = "SubjectOf";
            const strLocation = "Location";
            const strHashtags = "Hashtags";
            const strKeywords = "Keywords";
            const numCopyrightTxtYear = 2018;

            // New Elements
            // Title
            var elmTitle = document.createElement("h2");
            var elmTitleTxt = document.createTextNode(strTitle);
            // Caption
            var elmCaption = document.createElement("h3");
            var elmCaptionTxt = document.createTextNode(strCaption);
            // SubjectOf
            var elmSubjectOf = document.createElement("h3");
            var elmSubjectOfTxt = document.createTextNode(strSubjectOf);
            // Location
            var elmLocation = document.createElement("h3");
            var elmLocationTxt = document.createTextNode(strLocation);
            // Hashtags
            var elmHashtags = document.createElement("h3");
            var elmHashtagsTxt = document.createTextNode(strHashtags);
            // Keywords
            var elmKeywords = document.createElement("h3");
            var elmKeywordsTxt = document.createTextNode(strKeywords);
            // Copyright
            var elmCopyright = document.createElement("h4");
            var elmCopyrightTxt = document.createTextNode("");
            var elmTime = document.createElement("time");
            var elmTimeTxt = document.createTextNode(numCopyrightTxtYear);
            var elmCopyrightHolder = document.createElement("em");
            var elmCopyrightHolderTxt = document.createTextNode(" Evan Santé Photography")

            // <img src= "/images/nav/grid1.jpg" alt= "Thumbnail Image" itemprop= "hasPart image thumbnail" />
            //var objHeaderImage = document.createElement("img");

            // Set Element Nodes
            elmTitle.setAttribute("itemprop", "headline");
            elmTitle.appendChild(elmTitleTxt);
            elmCaption.setAttribute("itemprop", "caption");
            elmCaption.appendChild(elmCaptionTxt);
            elmSubjectOf.setAttribute("itemprop", "subjectOf");
            elmSubjectOf.appendChild(elmSubjectOfTxt);
            elmLocation.setAttribute("itemprop", "contentLocation");
            elmLocation.appendChild(elmLocationTxt);
            elmHashtags.setAttribute("itemprop", "keywords");
            elmHashtags.appendChild(elmHashtagsTxt);
            elmKeywords.setAttribute("itemprop", "keywords");
            elmKeywords.appendChild(elmKeywordsTxt);
            // Copyright
            elmTime.dateTime = numCopyrightTxtYear;
            elmTime.setAttribute("itemprop", "copyrightYear");
            elmCopyrightHolder.setAttribute("itemprop", "creator copyrightHolder");
            elmCopyrightHolder.appendChild(elmCopyrightHolderTxt);
            elmCopyright.append("© ");
            elmTime.appendChild(elmTimeTxt);
            elmCopyright.append(elmTime);
            elmCopyright.append(elmCopyrightHolder);


            // Append To Header
            elmHeader.appendChild(elmTitle);
            elmHeader.appendChild(elmCaption);
            elmHeader.appendChild(elmSubjectOf);
            elmHeader.appendChild(elmLocation);
            elmHeader.appendChild(elmHashtags);
            elmHeader.appendChild(elmKeywords);
            elmHeader.appendChild(elmCopyright);

            return elmHeaderFragment.appendChild(elmHeader);
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

[`append`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ParentNode/append) is fairly new and not supported in all browsers. However, the MDN page has a polyfill for it you can use on IE9-IE11 and, presumably, Edge.

If you don't use a polyfill, what you're looking for are `appendChild` ([spec](https://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#dom-node-appendchild) | [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/appendChild)) or `insertBefore` ([spec](https://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#dom-node-insertbefore) | [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/insertBefore)), which you call on the parent, passing in the node to append.

```
var parent = document.createElement("h4");
parent.appendChild(
    document.createTextNode("WHATEVER")
);
// ...presumably you `.appendChild(parent)` at some point...
```

Live Example:

```js
var parent = document.createElement("h4");
parent.appendChild(
    document.createTextNode("WHATEVER")
);
document.body.appendChild(parent);
```

`appendChild` always adds at the end of the parent. `insertBefore` adds before another node you specify (or at the end if you give `null` for the other node).

---

Having said that, `innerHTML` is universally supported and browsers are very fast at reading markup and turning it into DOM nodes. There's no reason not to use `innerHTML` when you have something complex you want to use as the content of an element. Naturally, though, you need `appendChild`, `insertBefore`, and other DOM methods in other situations.

---

In a comment you've said you want to append text to an existing text node: If so, just add to `nodeValue`:

```js
setTimeout(function() {
  var d = document.getElementById("target");
  var txt = d.firstChild;
  txt.nodeValue += " more text";
}, 800);
```

```html
<div id="target">existing text</div>
```

Comment: Sorry TJ that doesn't work:
// This is the Error when when 'appendChild' on 'Node': This node type does not support this method.

Comment: @CES: Look at the code and example in the answer carefully. Note, again, that you call `appendChild` on the **parent**, passing in the **child**. You can't call `appendChild` on a text node (`x` in your example) at all, text nodes can't have child nodes. (Edit: You've removed the code from your comment for some reason, but that's what the issue was with it.)

Comment: @TJCrowder sorry but I'm trying to append information into the txtnode NOT create a new node... .append is what I want and it works in every browser except Edge

Comment: @CES: You want to append text to an existing text node? That's really easy: `x.nodeValue += "the new text"` -- I've added to the answer.

Comment: @TJCrowder no i'm trying to create a new textnode and then populate it with a string of text and elements basically what i want is exactly what myNewElement.innerHTML would do... Unfortinaltly Node.appendChild() can only append one node to a noe and in rereading the .append Mozilla page it isn't supported in MSFT tech.

Comment: @CES: *"...then populate it with a string of text and elements ..."* Again: Text nodes cannot have children, you cannot put an element in a text node. That's what element nodes are for, as shown above. If you need to add more than one node to a parent, you call `appendChild` repeated, once with each node you want to add. I suggest stepping back from what you're currently doing and reading the DOM section of MDN and perhaps parts of the spec.